# Get Browser Culture Info in C#

Tags: asp.net, localization

[image]i am getting browser language but it returns an array Which is like this

```
tr-TR
tr;q=0,8
en-US;q=0,6
en;q=0,4
```

i am setting my browser language English(United State) and waiting only en-US how can only get en-US

i am using this code to get language

```
string[] languages = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages;

        if (languages == null || languages.Length == 0)
        {
        return null;
        }

        try
        {

        string language = languages[0].ToLowerInvariant().Trim();

        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
         return null;
        }
```

Comment: If you can only deliver content in en-US, why do you even care what the browser tells your application? The whole purpose of the list of languages is to tell your application which languages the owner of the browser wants, and in which order.

Comment: im am using chrome and i want to use langauge which is my browser lang.

Comment: Can you please explain what the question really is here? What about `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("tr-TR");` (obviously insert the value from the browser there)

Comment: when i change my browser language i want to get latest lang with my asp.net mvc application. But above code returns an language array and i don't decide which language is browser langauge

Comment: The language of your *browser* meaning the language that menu items and so on in the browser, that's *different* from that list of languages. That list of languages tells the web server which language(s) you prefer your content in. If you want your browser to request US english primary, remove turkey, or move it down the list so that English (United States) is at the top.

Comment: Ok, how can i get my browser menu item language. is it possible ?

Comment: No idea but you should clean up your question and change it to ask what you really want since that language list is something else. Specify in your question that you want to detect the language the browser presents its user interface in, such as dialog boxes and menu items, *not* the preferred language setting for the content.

Comment: Also, *why* do you want to detect that language?

Comment: when one user has entered my application from another country i want to set current language  System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(currentLang);
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;

Comment: **That's what the language list you already got is for**! If that user has said that Turkey is best, you should serve him turkish data (if possible), regardless if he has installed an english browser.

Comment: if he installed english browser i think he wants to use my application as english.

Comment: if you have any other idea to do this sitution please tell me i will search

Comment: Yes, rewrite your question and see if someone knows the answer. Right now you're asking about the language list, you obviously don't want to take that into account so rewrite your question to what you really want, perhaps someone knows how to do it, or if its possible.